# release dynamic memory for pointer member in c++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have a class:

```
class A {
    A();
    ////////something about the class A
};
```

then I have another class:

```
class B {
public:
    B();
    A* member_a;
};
B::B()
{
    this->member_a = new A();
}
```

what I want to do is like this:

```
main()
{
    vector<B> vec_b;
    int num=1;
    while(some_condition)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
            vec_b.pushback(B());
        }
        ////////do something about vec_b;
        num++;
    }
}
```

I know I am facing a memory leak issue because of the `new A()` in the constructor of `class B`. So I am trying to get help to release the memory after each `while` loop, which means to recycle all the memory that has been taken by the `vec_b` and all the objects of class B in the vector, the most important is to release the memory taken by class-A-objects.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You *do* know about destructors, right? And how to use the `delete` keyword? And if you always allocate in the constructor, why allocate dynamically at all? Don't use pointers if you don't actually have to.

Comment: "You wrote "I am trying to get help". This is not a question. Good luck in your quest to get some help. stackoverflow.com is where you get to ask specific questions on various topics. It is not where you go to get help with your code. If you do indeed figure out how to phrase a specific question, be sure to edit your post accordingly.

Comment: And if you don't know about destructors or the `delete` keyword, then I suggest you [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start over.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like it should be the job of `B`'s destructor

```
B::~B()
{
    delete member_a;
}
```

If you have access to C++11 or later, I would prefer `std::unique_ptr` so you get this deallocation for free

```
class B {
public:
    B();
    std::unique_ptr<A> member_a;
};

B::B()
{
    member_a = std::make_unique<A>();
}
```

Comment: `std::make_unique` is not available in `C++11`. It is C++14 feature

Comment: oh I didn't see your updated answer ,ya the same I thought

Comment: If no C++11 available, `std::auto_ptr` (possibly `const`) or `boost::scoped_ptr` can be used. Raw owning pointers should be very strongly discouraged.

Comment: Thanks, `make_unique` is not available for me. I tried to add `delete member_a` at the destructor, but the destructor is called when every 'for' loop is finished. at the second time of calling destructor, there will be a 'debug assertion failed' error.

Comment: Using unique_ptr is pointless in containers since memory is handled automatically therein.

Comment: @Poriferous In this particular case, you could store the object by value. But if you want the container to store a polymorphic object, then you must store a pointer, in which case a unique_ptr is certainly the way to go.

Comment: @CoryKramer But you don't have to store it in a `unique_ptr`! They are useless in containers and add unnecessary overhead to the CPU. You can just store the items with raw pointers like so: `vector<B*>`. The compiler couldn't care less if B were raw or had lube, it only cares if it can do its job as the programmer wanted.

Comment: @Poriferous Except when the container falls out of scope it won't delete any of those raw pointers, so you're back to square one and didn't answer the OPs question....

Comment: @CoryKramer They it shouldn't have been declared in scope to begin with. Besides, the container is declared within the main function so when the program is destroyed so is all the memory. :-))

Answer (score 0):

Write the delete in the destructor of class b

```
B::~B
{
delete member_a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the way you use the instance of the class A in your example, it seems to me that you don't actually need a pointer to A at all.

- If (and only if) you intend to create sub classes of the class A, then you should use a `std::unique_ptr` for the member instead of a raw pointer.
- If you don't intend to sub class the class A, then the best option for you is to simply create a solid instance of A inside the class B.

like this:

```
class B {
public:
    B();
    A member_a;
};
```

Having a solid instance of A inside the B class saves you from a lot of trouble with memory management.